# 'Best iPad stylus' question deleted as off topic

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I had a question about the best iPad stylus that would meet general needs and outperform the others. However, it was closed.

There's tons of "the best ...." questions; why was mine deleted? It's a good source of information for anyone looking to buy a decent stylus instead of wasting money on something cheap.

Comment: quick terminolgy briefer: *deleted* would mean it is gone from the page, only visible to people with 10k+ rep. Your question was *closed* meaning it's still visible but cannot be answered. Regardless it was probably closed as a shopping reccomendation, which of off-topic per the site FaQ - http://superuser.com/faq - sorry.

Comment: plus, iPad isn't a computer in the traditional sense; try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Best" questions asking for a list are generally frowned upon however some slip by and most are software related recommendations. Also they were quite popular when the site started before policy changed so I'm sure you can find plenty of examples. However in your case just to list a few reasons why it was closed

1. shopping recommendation
2. subjective (define "best" it may be different for you and me)
3. The Ipad is technically not a computer it's a tablet (I know it can be argued both ways but I think the consensus was tablet and cell phone questions are off topic) From the FAQ:
   **and it is not about …** "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer"
4. Your question isn't even about the Ipad itself its about the stylus (which I don't think it even comes with).

Any one of the above is a reason to close the question. In fact you say in your question above
"Its a good source of information for anyone looking to buy a decent stylus instead of wasting money on something cheap." Thus even if you ignore all the other reasons it is at the core a shopping recommendation.

Comment: Yeah when you say it that way it makes more sense. My bad, sorry folks